# Saving custom class to array in CoreData SwiftUI after closing app fails

Tags: core-data, swiftui, xcode11

I am getting the error below, when I close my app and then try to save to the core the when reloading the app.

> error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002291510 with userInfo (null)

When I first run the app fresh after deleting it off the simulator it works fine though once I close the program and try to add to the core again I get the error above.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State var objRating:[ObjectToRate]

    @FetchRequest(entity: ObjectsForRate.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ObjectsForRate.objectsClass, ascending: true)])
    var classesRetrieved: FetchedResults<ObjectsForRate>


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.objRating[0].name!)
            Button(action: {


                    print("Mark 1")
                let obj =  ObjectsForRate(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                obj.objectsClass = self.objRating



                do
                {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                }
                catch
                {
                    print("ERROR \(error)")
                }


            }) {
                Text("Insert to Core ")
            }
            Button(action: {
                print("---------")
                print(self.classesRetrieved.count)
                print(self.classesRetrieved)

            }) {
                Text("Retrieve")
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(objRating:data )
    }
}



public class ObjectToRate:NSObject, NSCoding
{
    public var name:String?


    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name

    }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name,forKey: "name")

    }

    public required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String

    }



}

var obj: ObjectToRate = {
    let o = ObjectToRate(name: "hi")
    return o
}()

var data = [
    obj
]
```

I've tried a lot of things but not sure what I'm doing wrong or if it is a bug.

Here is my Coredata model:
[image]

Another thing is when I retrieve the data from the core I get this:

```
<ObjectsForRate: 0x6000038fd400> (entity: ObjectsForRate; id: 0x8b8684e607da61d2 <x-coredata://0CDCAD97-CA46-402F-B638-3F0ACB6E30A7/ObjectsForRate/p5>; data: <fault>
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help.